# Can't get simple Enum example to work

Tags: java, enums

I have a simple Enum created

```
public interface Params
{
  public enum Locale 
  {
      UK("UK"), US("US");
      private String value;

      private Locale(String value) {
              this.value = value;
      }
  }; 

....
```

Here is my method I want to modify to take a Params.Locale attribute.

```
    public void doErrorQuery(Locale locale, String p_listStr)
    {
        if (p_spellingList == null)
        {
        result.setError(true);
        result.setErrorMessage("Null spelling list");
        return;
    }
```

I import my Locale enum using

```
import com.Params.Locale;
```

Problem is I can't get this to compile,  It's telling me it can't resolve the Locale.  Even if I use Params.Locale it does not work,  can't resolve name.

Comment: Are you sure the package name for the interface `Params` is 'com'?

Comment: Remove `return` statement from void method.

Comment: Could you add your stack trace please?

Comment: Why don't you declare the Locale enum as an own `Enum` which is not enclosed in `Params`?

Comment: @Miquel There will be no stacktrace if it doesn't compile.

Comment: I just showed some of the method,  the return is needed,  it's not the compilation issue in anycase. I don't have a stack trace as can't get it to compile. @user714965, how can I declare this enum in it's own ? Does it not need to be enclosed in a class?

Comment: That was it,  just created the Enum in it's own class,  I didn't know you could do that :) .  I always thought Enums had to be contained within a parent class

Comment: no, it does not need... it's a "class" itself (not a real class but considered as one). What you have there is also known as an nested class... you should read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @QuadroQ is correct. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13719605/474189) below - the code ought to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an own enum class for the enum. Doing this would be a cleaner design in my eyes:

```
public enum Locale {
   UK("UK"), US("US");
   private String value;

   private Locale(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the design questions for a second, there is nothing wrong with your original code. Perhaps you made a mistake with your package declarations? For me, the following code compiles just fine:

**Params.java**

```
package com;

public interface Params {

  public enum Locale {
    UK("UK"), US("US");
    private String value;

    private Locale(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

**TestClass.java**

```
package com;

import com.Params.Locale;

public class TestClass {

  public void test(Locale locale) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```